# Zillow webscraper issue

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape price history data from zillow, but I keep getting a Nonetype error. I realize it is telling me it can't find the element, but I have inspected the html content several times and I have the right class names.

If anybody could help I'd appreciate it.

Here is the link to the listing if you want to check out the html content yourself.
[Zillow Link](https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/407-N-9th-St-Las-Vegas-NV-89101/7014811_zpid/)

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the Zillow page to scrape
url = input('input url')

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the page with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the price history section
price_history_section = soup.find('div', {'class': 'hdp__sc-1j01zad-0 hGwlRq'})

# Find the table containing the price history data
price_history_table = price_history_section.find('table', {'class': 'hdp__sc-f00yqe-2 jaEmHG'})

# Find all the rows in the price history table
price_history_rows = price_history_table.find_all('tr', {'id': '1679961600000'})

# Loop through the rows and extract the data you want
for row in price_history_rows:
    # Extract the date
    date = row.find('td', {'class': 'hdp__sc-f00yqe-0 igpNxE'}).get_text().strip()

    # Extract the price
    price = row.find('td', {'class': 'hdp__sc-f00yqe-0 hdp__sc-reo5z7-3 gyUHSq hTabqA'}).get_text().strip()

    # Print the data
    print(f'{date}: {price}')
```

Here is the error:

```
line 17, in <module>
    price_history_table = price_history_section.find('table', {'class': 'hdp__sc-f00yqe-2 jaEmHG'})
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I tried to scrape a zillow listing for the price history. I expected it to print the price and date, but it gave me an error.

Comment: Zillow randomizes their class names, so the error means there's no such class in the source HTML anymore.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this issue that you know of

Comment: Could you add the HTML that contains the data you to your post?

Comment: I added the link that I am trying to scrape, so i am trying to scrape the price history table. I will add the html tomorrow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note: some divs and tags are dynamically loaded in by the webpage you use to inspect the element. That means, a tool like beautiful soup wont be able to access the data itself and will need an additional plugin... ignoring that for now...

Html parser doesn't work like that. I looked through the website and couldn't find a div with tag "hdp__sc-1j01zad-0 hGwlRq". You need to find the specific path to the div. What I mean is, what is that div contained in, and whats the thing inside of it contained in, etc all the way back to the top. The first div on the page is a div id "wrapper" with class "main-wrapper", then inside of that div the relevant one that points towards the price history would be the div with id "home-detail-lightbox-container"... and so on. Just be sure each div you call for is contained in the one previous. Its a bit tedious, but thats the way its done.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of anyways to search the WHOLE page for a specific div that's buried like that.

I hope this points you in the write direction. You seem to be on the right track with your code.

Comment: I did this and I setup selenium, but it's still not finding the element. Any ideas?

Comment: Because the CSS gets loaded in AND the class tags are randomized, I would suggest trying to apply for Zillows API for devs. This will make it 1000x easier to access the data you need using their documentation. Looks like the randomized tags is a way to keep people from scraping the site. https://www.zillowgroup.com/developers/

Comment: So I have been trying a different way and referencing the xpath. Weirdly it works sometimes, but then I'll do the same exact thing 10 seconds later and it can't find the path.

Comment: What does the snippet of code using the xpath look like?

Comment: wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//[@id="1680134400000"]/td[1]/span')))